# Displaying error next to input box instead of alert() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to display the error next to the input box instead of using the **`alert()`** method. So far, my code does not display anything when I enter a non-qualified number (for example, -10) - my code does not show the error message next to the **`"Enter Number"`**. When I use the **`alert()`** method, it shows up just fine. I suspect that I might have written the **`querySelector`** wrong somehow.

How may I fix this?

```js
// $ function is used to replace document.getElementById() in this document for convience
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

// determine if a number is prime
var isPrime = function( num ) {//step 1.1 add a parameter in function header to accept
// a number passed in
//step 1.2 add a for or while loop to check whether that number is prime or not
// if that number can be divisible by any integer between 2 and (number itself - 1)
// then that number is not a prime, return false

for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
if(num % i === 0) return false;
return true;

//step 1.3: after loop, return true, indicates that number is a prime

}

// get all prime numbers
var getPrimes = function ( num ){ //step 2.1 add a parameter in function header
var arr = [];
var primes = "";
var count = 0;
//step2.2: add a for or while loop
// inside the loop, call isPrime() function
// inside the loop, add prime number to primes string and update the count

for(var i = 2; i <= num; i++){
   if( isPrime(i) ) {
       count++;
       primes += i.toString() + " "
   }  
}
   arr.push( count );
   arr.push( primes );
   console.log(arr);
//step 2.3: return an array that holds both primes string and count
   return arr;
}
var processEntries = function() {
//get values from page
var input = $("number").value;
input = Number(input);
inputInteger = parseInt(input);
$("primes").value = "";
  
// add data validation here, to make sure the input is a number greater than 1
if ( isNaN(input) || input!== inputInteger || inputInteger <= 1){
//step 3.1: add js code to display a message says: "Please enter an integer number greater than 1."
//besides the input entry box
document.querySelector("number").innerHTML = "Invalid input for height, enter a non-negative number.";
  
$("count").value = "";
$("primes").value ="";
$("primes").style = "background-color: #808080";
$("count").style = "background-color: #808080";
}
else {
//step 3.2: add js code to remove error message if having one

$("primes").style = "background-color: #ccffff";
$("count").style = "background-color:#ccffff";
  
   arr = getPrimes( inputInteger );
   console.log(inputInteger);
//step 3.3: add js code to call getPrimes() function to display number of primes found in the range
// in the input box with id = "count"
   $("count").value = arr[0];
  
//step 3.4: add js code to call getPrimes() function to display the list of primes found in the textarea
// with id = "primes"
   $("primes").value = arr[1];
   console.log(arr[1]);
}
}
$("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
$("number").focus();
```

```css
/*@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wellfleet);*/
body {
    font-family: 'Wellfleet', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0 1em .5em;
}
h1 {
 color: blue;
 margin: .5em 0;
}
#teacher {
 float:right;
 margin:0px 30px 0px 0px;}

 
label {
 float: left;
    width: 10em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 5em;
 margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

textarea {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
span {
color: red;
font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css">
   
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Find Prime Numbers</h1>
  <img src="images/teacher.png" id="teacher" alt="teacher" width="177" height="277"/> 
        <p>Enter any a number to find out how many prime numbers there are
           up to and including that value.</p>
     
        <label for="number">Enter Number:</label>
        <input type="number" id="number" value="100">
        <span>&nbsp;</span><br>
  
        <label for="count">Prime count:</label>
        <input id="count" disabled><br>
        
        <label for="primes">Prime numbers:</label>
        <textarea id="primes" rows = "10" cols= "40" disabled></textarea><br>
        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input  type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
    </main>
    <script src="find_primeV2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **So far, my code does not display anything when I enter a non-qualified number (for example, -10)** uh, is there any validation at all? like in your `processEntries`? like do an `if(input < 0){$("some-id-to-the-error-message").style="display:block;color:red;"}`, here [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwgf5onm/).

Comment: I think I did include one, the `if ( isNaN(input) || input!== inputInteger || inputInteger <= 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all your query selector doesn't get the input. By doing the following you get the input.

```
document.querySelector("#number").value= "Invalid negative number"
```

Also notice `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` as an input wont show it's inner HTML.
But this code would show the error inside the input.

To show the error next to the input, simply put a span next to the input, give it an id an call it upon error.

```
<span id='displayError'><span>
```

and in your script

```
$('displayError').innerHTML = 'Invalid negative number'
```

Answer (score 1):

You used some jquery so i'll use it here:

```
// get the first span tag.
$("span").html("Invalid input for height");
```

Comment: use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/), as `html()` will print unescaped string which may undesirable for some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did try `$("span").html("Invalid input for height");` but it still does not return the error message :( I tried both `text(.)` and `innerHTML(.)` as well - but neither works. Any idea?

Comment: I think I read the code wrong. When you do `$("primes").style = "background-color: #ccffff";`, is that jquery to target the textarea or is that a variable of some kind?

Comment: I intended to target a text area actually

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. 2 things: 1 - see @pradipta's answer and 2) in jquery you need to target the ID with a `#`, and use the `css` method. So it should be `$("#primes").css("background-color", "#ccffff");`. Use `.style` in plain js.

Comment: Awesome! I got it. Thank you so much!